# struck in executing sqlite query using FMDB

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sqlite, fmdb

I am using FMDB framework for SQLite in one of my iPhone project.
The code is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CatID.count; i++) 
{ 
    NSString *subCatId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM expense 
    where CAT_ID = %@ AND CURR_ID = %@ 
    AND EXP_DATE BETWEEN '%@' AND '%@' ",
    [CatID objectAtIndex:rowTrip],
    [currID objectAtIndex:1],
    _fromTextField.text,
    _toTextField.text];

    FMResultSet *result = [database executeQuery:subCatId];

    while([result next]) 
    {
        [_total addObject:[result stringForColumn:@"AMOUNT"]];
    }

}
```

1. `CatID` is fixed i.e it is given by the user.
2. `carrID` is fetched with for loop and is queried.

Every time after the SQL query, `_total` array is incremented (new object is added) but this is hanging.

Let's say we have `"AMOUNT"` output is 100, and `CatID.count` times objects are being added to `_total` array. Please tell me where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While executing SQL queries, **DONT** use `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` method. Instead, just use the query as it is and pass arguments along the string in `[database executeQuery:]`.

Try the following:

```
NSMutableArray* _total = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < [CatID count]; i++) 
{ 
    NSString *subCatId_QUERY = @"SELECT * FROM expense 
    where CAT_ID = %@ AND CURR_ID = %@ 
    AND EXP_DATE BETWEEN '%@' AND '%@' ";


    NSNumber* rowTrip  = [[CatID objectAtIndex:rowTrip] intValue];
    NSNumber* currID   = [[currID objectAtIndex:1] intValue];

    NSString* fromDate = _fromTextField.text;
    NSString* toDate   = _toTextField.text;

    FMResultSet *result = [database executeQuery:subCatId_QUERY,rowTrip,currID, fromDate, toDate];

    while([result next]) 
    {
        [_total addObject:[result stringForColumn:@"AMOUNT"]]; //are you sure about this? string??
    }

}
```